# screen recorder that saves incoming audio

Tags: windows, linux, screen-recording, video-conferencing, skype

I am going to be joining a couple of Skype sessions and I would like to record just the screen and incoming audio. Is there an screen recorder for Skype that can record incoming audio but not outgoing audio?

I would like this to be available for Windows and/or Linux operating systems.

Comment: By out going audio, you mean what your mic is picking up for the call, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if [this program](http://www.pistonsoft.com/skype-recorder.html) has an option to filter out outgoing audio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OBS is great and covers your usage case and more:

https://obsproject.com/

Open Broadcaster Software is free and open source software for video recording and live streaming. Supported features include:

- Encoding using H264 (x264) and AAC.
- Support for Intel Quick Sync Video (QSV) and NVENC.
- Unlimited number of scenes and sources.
- Live RTMP streaming to Twitch, YouTube, DailyMotion, Hitbox and more.
- File output to MP4 or FLV.
- GPU-based game capture for high performance game streaming.
- DirectShow capture device support (webcams, capture cards, etc).
- Windows 8 high speed monitor capture support.
- Bilinear or lanczos3 resampling.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [WebCam Recorder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stLmSXuWuDc), installation and use of this program makes it one the favorites because it allow the use to record high quality videos, crystal clear voice recording and a very powerful and useful video and audio converter
How to use it?

1. Just click on “record”
2. Choose an option for your recording:

   a.    Just audio: export the call and saves it in MP3 format

   b.    Picture in picture: normal skype call

   c.    Side by side; your image next to the other person’s

   d.    Webcam local: records everything that happens in your pc

   e.    Remote web cam: records the other person

   f.    Separate archives: record video and audio separate files
3. That’s it, now you can record as many conversation as you like

Hope it works for you :D

Comment: Link no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

**[Evaer](http://www.evaer.com/index.htm)** - excellent Skype video & audio recorder features
[image: Evaer's Interface]

- Capture original Skype video and audio data to record with high quality.
- Supports recording single Skype video calls, Skype screen sharing sessions and up to 10 way Skype group video calls.
- Record Skype video calls directly to your hard disk with picture-in-picture, side-by-side, separate files, audio-only, local-webcam-only and remote-webcam-only mode.
- Changeable recording video codec, video resolution (supports 240p, 360p, 480p, 720p, 1080p), aspect ratio (4:3, 16:9) and frame rate.
- Self-adaptive selection of video resolution and aspect ratio.
- Save Skype video message and Skype voicemail directly to your hard disk.
- Option to record Skype video calls into MP4 or AVI files.
- Option to record separate MP3 audio files with video calls.
- Option to record both sides sound, local sound only and remote sound only.
- Automatically record MP3 audio files if audio calls only.
- Answering machine for Skype video and voice incoming calls.
- Automatic chat reply.
- Easy to use with friendly UI.

As long as you have Evaer on "Record Skype video calls with remote-webcam-only mode", you will be able to record incoming video & audio. It currently cost $19.95 for a license.