# Record screen with audio in background (Windows)

Tags: windows, screen-recording

I'm looking for a Windows program that can record my screen and the audio with that application while I'm doing other stuff on my computer.

For example, I would like to record a live lecture on zoom and the audio with that app. At the same time, I would like to use my computer to do other stuff, e.g. work in word, but I want the recording to only be of zoom and zoom's audio.

Comment: You can use ShareX.https://getsharex.com/.

Comment: @compenthusiast Well, I downloaded it, but it still doesn't allow me to record anything else than the active window. So that doesn't really help much

Comment: you need to add ffmpeg go to task settings and screen recording settigs.Watch a video probably.

Comment: This is relevant too : https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21288/screen-recorder-that-saves-incoming-audio?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

A license for Microsoft Teams enables this. I recommend it because it's Microsoft's own product and not third party so viruses are not an issue like if you accidentally download a third party apps. While we could help set it up you could managed to do it yourself period

disclosure: we are Microsoft partner

Answer (score 0):

OBS will do it for free. (And a LOT more)
https://obsproject.com/download

And how to...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFhbQlOX4yw